# How to put key-value as key for other Map?

Tags: java

I want to put values in HashMap like below,

```
    map1.put("A",3);

    map1.put("A",5);
    map1.put("B",4);
    map1.put("B",8);
```

now I want to make ("A",3) key/value pair as key for other map like,
let say ("A",3) is key1 same way for others
map2.put(key1, abc);

same way for others. can you please help me to do like this???

Comment: Note that there's a slight mistake in your code. HashMap may have only one value corresponding to one key, so in your case after execution it would contain only two key-value pairs: ("A",5) and ("B",8).

Comment: I wonder why you would like to do that. How are you thinking to lookup values in your second map afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

You can get first hashMap `entrySet` and use it as key for second hashMap.

[entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) returns

> Set view of the mappings contained in this map

For example,

1) Set firstMapEntries = map1.entrySet();

2) Create secondmap

3) Iterate firstMapEntries.

4)Add to second map secondMap.put(firstMapEntry, "abc")

Comment: I know the same but can you please provide details?

Answer (score 0):

You can get those (key, value) pairs as a set using the [`entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method. Iterate over that set and use the elements as keys in your other `HashMap`.

Something like this:

```
// given HashMap<String, Integer> map1:
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map1.entrySet())
    map2.put(entry, "some string value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can store them in a Pair like this:

```
class Pair
{
    public String first;
    public Integer second;

    public Pair(String first, Integer second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Then create a HashMap of Pair - String pairs:

```
HashMap<Pair, String> map = new HashMap<Pair, String>();
```

Comment: Any class used as key in a hash-based structure must. Implement `equals` and `hashcode`